# interface builder code depository

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

There are two ways to do things in xcode, programmatically or through Interface Builder. Where is the code Interface Builder writes? Presumably if one could see this code one might understand how to approach coding programmatically. How can one see the code Interface Builder creates? 
Thanks

Comment: Huh? There is no code written by Interface Builder.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am a novice here, however, for example, when you create objects programmatically you are required to position the x y cordinates and the size. Does IB do the same? Does it create objects as code? Can one see this code?

Answer (score 0):

Interface Builder generates XML. You can view the generated code by right-clicking the storyboard file and selecting Open as -> Source Code. I would advise against modifying or writing XML instead of using Interface Builder. If you cannot do something in Interface Builder, you should use Objective-C or Swift. So looking at the Storyboard XML won't help much.